# How long can I stay in New Zealand if I’m applying tourists visa

Tags: tourist-visas, new-zealand

I need to visit my bf in NZ so I’m applying for tourists visa

Comment: If you plan to live with your boyfriend, also look into what is needed to immigrate, as you may find it easier to do so when you set out to do it from the start.

Comment: There seems little point in applying for a visa right now, given that it’s uncertain when New Zealand will lift entry restrictions https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/international-travel-document-news/1580226297.htm

Comment: Firstly, you'll find it difficult to get to New Zealand at present: there are only a handful of international flights arriving and they're mostly carrying freight. Secondly, all international arrivals are required to spend two weeks in a government mandated quarantine facility before entering the country. This requirement will remain in place for the foreseeable future - possibly until a coronavirus vaccine is available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [New Zealand Immigration web site](https://www.immigration.govt.nz/new-zealand-visas/apply-for-a-visa/about-visa/visitor-visa#https://www.immigration.govt.nz/new-zealand-visas/apply-for-a-visa/visa-factsheet/conditions/visitor-visa):

> You can visit New Zealand as a genuine tourist for up to 9 months in
>   an 18-month period.
>
> - The 18-month period is calculated backwards from the last day you intend to be in New Zealand.
> - If the last day you’ll be here is 1 December, then your 18-month period will begin on 1 June of the year before.
>
> You can apply for another 3 months’ stay and extend your stay to 12
>   months in a 24-month period, if:
>
> - you need more time to complete your tourist itinerary
> - you can’t leave New Zealand for reasons beyond your control
> - you’ve applied for residence for the first time.
>
> To apply for another 3 months’ stay, you must have financially
>   supported yourself and not worked, studied or been sponsored during
>   your stay.
>
> If you’ve recently visited New Zealand for a total of 12 months, you
>   have to remain outside New Zealand for 12 months before you can apply
>   for another Visitor Visa.

Of course it is a bad idea to apply for a visa and ask for the maximum allowable time unless you have very strong personal circumstances. If they believe you cannot support yourself for your intended duration of stay, or that you intend to work in New Zealand, your visa will likely be refused.

Comment: Do I need a return ticket with me? I’m planning to stay until 9 months straight. If that possible?

Comment: @Hanna You should read that web site for all the details; it has the answers to most of your questions, including that one. Yes, you need an onward ticket.